# DTO Api Platform v3

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

Using the v3 of Api Platform, I'm encountering the following problems when working with DTO:

- The @id field looks like "/.well-known/genid/01e546d3f38c0b5d3b8a", and I don't find anyway to get the IRI of the entity instead.
- How to initialize the DTO when working with PUT/PATCH methods, in v2 I was using ApiPlatform\Core\DataTransformer\DataTransformerInitializerInterface.

I've tried different solutions and digged in into the source code before asking, and i don't find any way to solve these two problems.

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You now have to set your GET operation on the DTO in order to have the @id field correctly generated, see [this issue](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/5451) for reference.

So if you have this entity:

```php
<?php
#[Get(
        output: MyEntityDTO::class,
        provider: MyEntityProvider::class
)]
class MyEntity {
    private int $id;
}
```

You'll have this DTO:

```php
<?php
#[Get(shortName: 'MyEntity')]
class MyEntityDTO {
    public int $id;
}
```

Note that you have to set the shortName to allow having all your operation under the same MyEntity tag in the swagger documentation.

For your second question, you now have to use Providers and Processors to handle the state of your data in api-platform v3, see the [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/main/core/dto/). In the case of a PUT/PATCH operation, you'll have to use a processor.

Comment: I've tried this for a Patch operation but does not work... any Idea plz ? the id is always NULL.